# Optimization in python, equality constraints

Tags: python, optimization, constraints, nonlinear-optimization, minimization

I am very new to optimization and scientific programming in Python.
Right now I am learning from a paper where the following optimization problem occurs:

minimize f(x1, x2, x3, x4) (where f is continuous)

subject to

sum(x1, x2, x3, x4) = 1,

xi real-valued in (0,1)

and

g(x1,x2)=g(x2,x3)

for some continuous constraint function g.

Has anyone a suggestion for an easy-to-use library (preferably in Python or R) for solving this optimization problem and could provide me with a code snippet showing how to use it?
(Performance is not very important for me.)

I really have no idea how to tackle this issue since I am very new to this whole topic. A little guidance how to build a setup for this problem would be very appreciated!!

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: This might help you. {https://realpython.com/linear-programming-python/}

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you need SciPy library which is often is built-in with Anaconda
Here is an example of an optimization for multi scalar.
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html#id21